# How does Windows 'break up' the pictures from the .msstyles files?

Tags: windows, themes

I'm talking about this =>

[Stream bitmaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRleS.png)

I'm curious, how does Windows use the individual bitmaps on that file? Does Windows have some sort of cropping tool to break them up every time it has to use them? I can't seem to find any information.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Implement a similar feature in your own code?

Comment: Yes. Exactly Yakov.

Comment: @Nels King: Look at the following posts too: 1) [How to parse an .msstyles file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291624/how-to-parse-an-msstyles-file) 2) [How to apply a .msstyles to a .NET app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889024/6630084)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a normal practice to load a bigger bitmap and then use parts of it when drawing (sometimes called an **atlas**). I'm not familiar with `.msstyles` specifically, but assuming that you have the meta-data necessary to determine where each element is located within the bitmap, you can draw just that part using GDI functions like `BitBlt`, `StretchBlt` or `AlphaBlend`.

These functions take the region of the source bitmap they need to blit as a parameter, rather than operating on the entire bitmap. For example, the [signature for `AlphaBlend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) looks like this:

```
BOOL AlphaBlend(
  HDC           hdcDest,
  int           xoriginDest,
  int           yoriginDest,
  int           wDest,
  int           hDest,
  HDC           hdcSrc,
  int           xoriginSrc,
  int           yoriginSrc,
  int           wSrc,
  int           hSrc,
  BLENDFUNCTION ftn
);
```

If we are to draw a 16x16 icon that's located at x=100,y=200 within the skin bitmap, we can do that as follows:

```
AlphaBlend(hdcDest, xoriginDest, yoriginDest, 16, 16, skinDc, 100, 200, 16, 16, blend);
```

Note that the actual Windows theming implementation may not do it this way, but rather split image into smaller chunks in order to reduce the memory consumption, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer C#, but this is fine. I also develop in C/C++.